# Laravel Passport createToken error (DateTimeImmutable)

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

when I try to upgrade laravel 6 to laravel 7.

I experience the error below:

[image]

Then when I have tried to downgrade again, the error still appears. Whereas previously there was no such error. If I traced the error occurred at `createToken()`.

Please help.

Comment: please share your error message here

Comment: Can you place more code / context?

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by downgrade version of this package 'lcobucci/jwt',

> composer require lcobucci/jwt "3.3.x"